# Image processing with Python: how to find the average pixel distance between 2 contrasting regions over an entire image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

For lab data of a magnetic domain structure am trying to find the distance between two contrasting regions,e.g. the purple and yellow regions:

[image][NEW PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqVjM.png)

I have downloaded OpenCV and skimage for the purpose but am at a loss. I have found a code that performs edge detection and closes gaps in between object edges, and then finds contours in the edge map, but even if I calculate a distance successfully using this method I wouldn't know how to perform the calculation over the entire image.

What I am trying to accomplish: find the average distance (in pixels) between two edges of the dark grey region which are separated by the light grey regions over the entire image

code so far:

```
def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)

#perform edge detection and close gaps in between object edges:
edged = cv2.Canny(kerr, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

# find contours in the edge map
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
```

Comment: How can the distance between two contrasting regions be greater than 0? They are touching each other.

Comment: that's a tiny picture. do you have anything better than a thumbnail?

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended image processing question. It would help if you described exactly what you'd like to accomplish, and show the code that you've written so far to achieve that outcome. For example, what is "distance" here? There are many blue and yellow points, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @bnaecker I have uploaded a new picture as requested by christoph and I have added white lines in the lower left to show the distance I am trying to find.  have also made a sentence at the end sharing exactly what I am trying to do: find the average distance (in pixels) between two edges of the dark grey region which are separated by the light grey regions over the entire image. I have attached what I have so far, although I do not mind starting over, because I had found this on the internet, so I haven't lost much time..

Comment: the larger picture you posted has some debris/defects... those are bothersome. and the lighting is uneven. -- highpass to fix the lighting. maybe a median blur to suppress noise. then threshold, gradient/edges using morphology, then you'd have a map of the boundary like so: https://i.imgur.com/DwoubUU.png -- distance transform on that, tells you the thickness of these labyrinth paths. then non-maximum suppression, or not. then I think you'd have some progress.

Comment: or consider a laplacian pyramid and do statistics on that, like which level has how much response. that gives a measure of the "granularity"

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a medial axis skeletonization : https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/auto_examples/plot_medial_transform.html

It will return a long list of measures (one per point of the skelet). Find the maximum in the list (or the minimum, or the mean, depending on wat you want...), multiply it by 2 (because it's radius), and you will get the width of the light grey regions.

Comment: Oh wow, that would have worked perfectly. If only I had seen this, ah well, for the next person who needs to calculate domain wall width for a lab. :) Or if he says that my data analysis was not good, and I have to revise it, although it is a physics class, so usually they are less harsh with developing programming skills.. I actually ended up doing sorta this manually with the distance transform provided above (then found the maximum, took half of the values under the maximum and multiplied by two). Noob programmer problems.  Probably not too precise, but it didnt have to be.